# Delete and remove a pointer from a list

Tags: c++, list, pointers, memory

I have this code (its a smol version of the code that replicates the error) and it gives a some kind of error with memory. idk just pls help me fix it. It deletes the object so there remains just the nullptr. Idk why but it doesn't want to remove the pointer from the list.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
// casual include
```

here i create a class thats the base for all of my other classes

```
class Object // a virtual class
{
public:
    bool needs_delete = false;

    virtual void tick() {}
    virtual void render() {}
};
```

a player class that inherits from the Object class i created earlier

```
class Player : public Object
{
public:
    float x, y; // <-- just look at da code dont read dis

    Player(float x, float y) : // i initialize the "x" & "y" with the x & y the user has set in the constructor
        x(x), y(y)
    {}

    void tick() override // just look at the code
    {
        x++;
        if (x > 10000)
        {
            needs_delete = true;
        }
    }

    void render() override // just look at the code
    {
        // nothing...
    }
};
```

just the main function. at this point im just writing text because stackoverflow wont let me post this piece of constant depression. pls help :)

```
int main()
{
    std::list<Object*>* myObjs = new std::list<Object*>; // a list that will contain the objects

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) // i create 1k player just for testing
    {
        myObjs->push_back(new Player(i, 0));
    }

    while (true)
    {
        if (myObjs->size() == 0) // if there are no objects i just break out of the loop
            break;
        
        for (Object* obj : *myObjs) // update the objects
        {
            obj->tick();
            obj->render();

            // some other stuff
        }


        // DA PART I HAVE NO IDEA HOW TO DO
        // pls help cuz i suck

        for (Object* obj : *myObjs) // help pls :)
        {
            // baisicly here i want to delete the object and remove it from the list
            if (obj->needs_delete)
            {
                std::cout << "deleted object\n";
                delete obj;
                myObjs->remove(obj);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please create a single-piece MRE, [mre]. I.e. try to demonstrate your problem in one copy-pastable code file. If you shrink it as much as possible and add some description of what you observe then SO will not prevent you from posting your MRE.

Comment: Have you tried remove_if? It works with lambda too.

Comment: There is actually multiple issues with the code. You should not delete from list while iterating through it, when you call `delete obj` you set obj to nullptr and therefore you can't call myObjs->remove(nullptr)

Comment: The problem is that you're removing elements from the list as you're iterating over it.

Comment: @Po1nt `delete obj` does not modify `obj`.

Comment: Why are you doing `std::list<Object*>* myObjs = new std::list<Object*>`  instead of just `std::list<Object*> myObjs;`? You're leaking memory right now.

Comment: Personally I would just get rid of all the new's and delete's in your code, they are not necessary. Specifically when combined with remove_if. If you're interested I can make a small example for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

```
myObjs->remove_if([](auto& pObj)
{
    if ( pObj->needs_delete )
    {
        delete pObj;
        return true;
    }
    else 
        return false;
});
```